# how to filter data by condition to make the number of rows to be the same for each group

Tags: r, filter, group-by, rows

This is my sample data:

```
date label  type exdate    x       y       z       w
 1    10     A     2      15      0.25    0.35   13.49
 1    10     A     2      12.5    1.30    1.45   13.49  
 1    10     B     2      10      1.7     1.8    13.49  
 1    10     B     2      12.5    0.3     0.4    13.49
 1    10     B     2      17.5    1.8     0.3    13.49
 1    11     A     3      15      0.75    0.8    13.49  
 1    11     A     3      12.5    1.8     1.9    13.49  
 1    11     A     3      17.5    0.2     0.35   13.49  
 1    11     B     3      10      0.1     0.25   13.49  
 1    11     B     3      15      2.15    2.3    13.49  
 1    11     B     3      12.5    0.8     0.85   13.49  
 1    11     B     3      17.5    4.1     4.3    13.49  
 2    11     A     4      10      3.7     4      13.49
 2    11     A     4      15      1       1.1    13.49   
 2    11     A     4      12.5    2.05    2.2    13.49  
 2    11     A     4      17.5    0.4     0.55   13.49  
 2    11     B     4      10      0.3     0.4    13.49  
 2    11     B     4      15      2.45    2.6    13.49  
 2    11     B     4      12.5    1.05    1.15   13.49  
 2    11     B     4      17.5    4.3     4.6    13.49
```

Firstly, I will group my data set by c(date,label,exdate), and for each group it will be A and B inside variable 'type'. **BUT**  I want to let the number of rows for type A and type B is the same.

Filter conditions:

- To make data to be the same number of rows, the distance between x and w should be same or almost the same for any pairs of type A and type B.

For example:

```
 type   x     w 
  A     2    3.5
  A     3    3.5
  A     4    3.5
  B     1    3.5
  B     2    3.5

 # The output after filter
 type   x     w 
  A     2    3.5 (pair with type_B ; x = 1)
  A     3    3.5 (pair with type_B ; x = 2)
  B     1    3.5
  B     2    3.5
```

So, for the sample data above, the result I hope:

```
date label  type exdate    x       y       z       w
 1    10     A     2      15      0.25    0.35   13.49
 1    10     A     2      12.5    1.30    1.45   13.49      
 1    10     B     2      12.5    0.3     0.4    13.49
 1    10     B     2      17.5    1.8     0.3    13.49
 1    11     A     3      15      0.75    0.8    13.49  
 1    11     A     3      12.5    1.8     1.9    13.49  
 1    11     A     3      17.5    0.2     0.35   13.49      
 1    11     B     3      15      2.15    2.3    13.49  
 1    11     B     3      12.5    0.8     0.85   13.49  
 1    11     B     3      17.5    4.1     4.3    13.49  
 2    11     A     4      10      3.7     4      13.49
 2    11     A     4      15      1       1.1    13.49   
 2    11     A     4      12.5    2.05    2.2    13.49  
 2    11     A     4      17.5    0.4     0.55   13.49  
 2    11     B     4      10      0.3     0.4    13.49  
 2    11     B     4      15      2.45    2.6    13.49  
 2    11     B     4      12.5    1.05    1.15   13.49  
 2    11     B     4      17.5    4.3     4.6    13.49
```

To make this result, how can I code? Is it insert else if condition inside filter()?

Comment: Hi, I'm wondering, how do you define the distance? And what are the values of `x` and `z` in your example? Those do not match values from your sample data and nor your results.

Comment: @Adela  I defined the distance as `w` - `x`. If you are mention about y and z, it just only the other variables I needed to used later